# What can be said about this double sum?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, elementary-proofs

> **Question.** Can this number be expressed in terms of classical values?
>   $$\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(n^2+m^2)^{\frac32}}=1.056348517615643291\dots$$

**UPDATE.** I'm encouraged by Noam, Kevin and Igor's directional replies. To spice things up, I ask: is this true?
$$\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(n^2+m^2)^s}=\zeta(s)\beta(s)-\zeta(2s),$$
wherever convergence occurs. Here, $\zeta(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ are the [Riemann zeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Dirichlet beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) functions, respectively.

Comment: How did you compute it so accurately, out of interest? It's not here http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html so that's evidence for "no", but of course not a proof.

Comment: I don't know how the OP computed it, but if you multiply each term by $(-1)^{m+n}$ you get an elementary multiple of the same sum that can be computed using **altsum** recursively.

Comment: [Correction: this requires first adding $\zeta(3)$ to get the sum over $m>0$.    Also: that makes it the value at $3/2$ of the zeta function for the Gaussian numbers, and it is known that such values can be computed efficiently.  In GP: **zetak(zetakinit(x^2+1),3/2) - zeta(3)** .  Or, using the factorization into the product of Riemann zeta and Dirichlet L: **zeta(3/2)*sumalt(n=0,(-1)^n/(2*n+1)^(3/2)) - zeta(3)** ]

Comment: @KevinBuzzard: I had help from a friend with computer power in CS.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: sounds interesting. Proof?

Comment: See Kevin's and Igor's answers below.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies : you should upgrade your pari set-up; zetakinit doesn't exist any more (you would rather have fresh new bugs than old fixed ones, right?)

Comment: @KevinBuzzard do you know why zetakinit would have been removed?  I liked that command for the purpose of generating numerical examples.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan why do you say you "claim" that formula for general $s$ instead of just saying it is true?  Instead of writing $\beta(s)$ in the formula it would be more standard (at least within number theory) to call it $L(s,\chi_4)$ where $\chi_4$ is the nontrivial character modulo 4.

Comment: Hey Keith. I think it's been replaced rather than removed. zetak(zetakinit(x^2+1),3/2) doesn't work (at least on my set-up: v2.8.1 beta) but lfun(lfuncreate(x^2+1),3/2) does. I think they put in lots more L-function stuff recently; maybe this is some sort of attempt to normalise the notation?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan yes, your claim is true, and a relatively simple proof goes via interpreting the product of Riemann zeta and Dirichlet beta as the Dedekind zeta function of the Gaussian integers. Beat that for mathematician-name-dropping in one sentence! It's what Noam has been saying all along in fact.

Comment: @KConrad: Thanks. I changed the "claim" to a question. As for $\beta(s)$, you might be right but I just like $\beta$ (a personal taste).

Comment: So if we let n.m start from 0 (but not be both 0), we get $ζ(s)β(s)$?

Comment: let one of them start from 0 and the other from 1.  You want to catch exactly once each nonzero orbit of integer points (m,n) up to 90-degree rotations.

Comment: There is a question about this sum on math.SE: [Convergence of $1/(x^2+y^2)^a$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1210359). One of the answers expresses the sum in the form $S_\alpha = -\zeta(2\alpha)+\zeta(\alpha)\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^{\alpha}}$. Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%2Cm%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac1%7B(n%5E2%2Bm%5E2)%5Es%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know how "classical" you find these values, but here's perhaps something.

Define $E=\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{m^2+n^2}$, which is known to be a weight 1 level 4 modular form. In fact $E$ is an eigenform for the Hecke operators, and if we write $E=\sum_{r\geq0}a_rq^r$ then $L(E,s)=\sum_{r\geq1}a_r/r^s$ equals $4\zeta(s)L(\chi,s)$ with $\chi$ the Dirichlet character of conductor 4. The factor of 4 is because $E$ is normalised so that $a_1=4$. Note that $a_r$ equals the number of ways $r$ can be written as $m^2+n^2$ (where we allow zero and negative values for $m$ and $n$ at this point). Note also that the $L$-function doesn't see the troublesome $m=n=0$ term.

Now note that setting $s=3/2$ (where everything converges) we get $L(E,3/2)$ is nearly what you want. In fact if your constant is $c$ then (allowing for signs) we get

$$4c+4\sum_{n\geq1}(1/n^2)^{3/2}=L(E,3/2)$$

($4c$ for the signs, and the other term for the $m=0$ and $n=0$ terms we missed out) and all the 4s cancel miraculously giving

$c=\zeta(3/2)L(\chi,3/2)-\zeta(3)$

or equivalently

$c=\zeta_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}(3/2)-\zeta(3)$

with $\zeta_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}$ the Dedekind zeta function of the number field. Let's check with pari-gp:

```
L=lfuncreate(x^2+1);
lfun(L,3/2)-zeta(3)

%2 = 1.0563485176156432910328906583178146441
```

which looks good to me.

Note finally that now I've done the calculation I realise that one could avoid the modular forms side of things and just consider the zeta function of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ directly because we're summing some function of norms of elements; the final equation for $c$ follows essentially from the definition of the Dedekind $\zeta$ function.

Hmm, and now note finally finally that while I was typing this, Noam Elkies said exactly the same thing but rather more succinctly :-)

Comment: This is cool, indeed. Thanks also to Noam.

Comment: @Kevin Buzzard, this series is classical. It has been calculated in 1871 by L. Lorenz. I gave an answer below. There is also a classic textbook on lattice sums.

Answer (score 6):

This is (almost) rehashing what has been said but with an intent to spell things out.

Begin with the observation that
$$\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(n^2+m^2)^s}=\frac14\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{r_2(k)}{k^s}-\zeta(2s).$$
Using $r_2(k)=4\sum_{d\vert k}\left(\frac{-4}k\right)=4(1*\left(\frac{-4}k\right))(k)$, where $\left(\frac{a}b\right)$ is the Jacobi symbol,
and $\left(\frac{-4}{2k}\right)=0, \left(\frac{-4}{2k+1}\right)=(-1)^k$, 
while the Dirichlet series evolves under the arithmetic convolution, i.e., $\sum\frac{(a*b)(k)}{k^s}=\sum\frac{a(k)}{k^s}\sum\frac{b(k)}{k^s}$, it follows that
\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{r_2(k)}{k^s}
&=4\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1*\left(\frac{-4}k\right))(k)}{k^s}
=4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^s}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{-4}k\right)(k)}{k^s} \\
&=4\zeta(s)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^s}=4\zeta(s)\beta(s).
\end{align}

Comment: Yes -- this is an explanation of my claim that $L(E,s)=4\zeta(s)\beta(s)$.

Answer (score 6):

Exhaustive analysis of lattice sums can be found in the book [Lattice sums then and now](http://www.cambridge.org/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9781107039902). This book can be found for free on the web.

OP's sum is given by formula 1.3.14 on page 33:[image]

L. Lorenz. Bidrag tiltalienes theori. Tidsskrift Math., 1:97–114, 1871.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/76158)

Comment: @AndrásBátkai , Igor Rivin gave answer in the same manner. Why didn't you wrote this comment to his answer?

Comment: Also if the linked page changes then one still will be able to find the book by its title. I don't see any problem here.

Comment: Igor's answer, while it could be made better along these lines, at least points to an online article that isn't behind a paywall, and was specific enough to know where in the paper to turn to (the first section), while also connecting with other answers/comments. Usually just referring to an entire book isn't so useful. Perhaps you could quote a precise result in the book that answers the question, and include a page number?

Comment: @ToddTrimble, the book I cited is not behind a paywall. All the books can be found for free, if one knows where to look.

Comment: Thanks for your addition, Nemo; that's very helpful. I am of course aware of "where to look", but that's not something we can point to directly here without potential trouble. Your original link seems to be to a vendor, but anyway your current answer is a big improvement; +1.

Answer (score 5):

To give yet a third version of Kevin and Noam's answer, check out [Paul Garett's notes](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_c/factorization_zetas.pdf) where he shows how to factorize the Zeta function of the Gaussian integers.